# How to bind server value in javascript onmousedown in aspx page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

I have one Hyperlink in aspx page. I need to do two things

1. When I Navigate from mousedown I need to log some activity
2. While logging EmployeeID value I need to bind from server.

But i am facing error like server tags not properly formed.

Below is my code:

```
   <asp:HyperLink id="hyperlink1" 
              NavigateUrl="#"
              Text="EMPLOYEE ID"
 onmousedown="javascript:record('User clicked Eployee ID=') +<%#fasteval("EmpID")%>     
              runat="server"/>
```

Note: record is my function which will log into database one thing i want to bind the `EmpID` value from my own column `EmpID`.

Can you please help me on this

Comment: Can you show rendered `html` of your above `hyperlink` and also your `record function`

Comment: Hi Guruprasad It has been rendered like that <a id="_EmpID" onmousedown="javascript:record('User clicked Eployee ID=')" href="";>1002876</a>

Answer (score 0):

You have unescaped double quote in double quote, use single quote for outer most quotes for `onmousedown` event handler.

```
 <asp:HyperLink id="hyperlink1" 
              NavigateUrl="#"
              Text="EMPLOYEE ID"
 onmousedown='javascript:record("User clicked Eployee ID=") +<%#fasteval("EmpID")%>'     
              runat="server"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `string.format`

```
<asp:HyperLink id="hyperlink1" 
          NavigateUrl="#"
          Text="EMPLOYEE ID"
onmousedown='<%# string.Format("javascript:record('User clicked Eployee ID= {0}')", Eval("EmpID")) %>'
          runat="server"/>
```